Meaning of あんたの今 here
From the anime Black Lagoon, chief of police warns main character Revy that the current trouble she’s caught up in now as a smuggler is serious (involving a crime syndicate and various stuff that threatens U.S. national security):

えっとそうミス ･ レヴェッカ.
バッファロー ･ ヒルの所長と ―
ＮＹＰＤ 二七分署の連中があんたの今を知ったら
―
腰を抜かすかもしれないな
Oh, and Miss Rebecca! If the chief at Buffalo Hill and if
the NYPD 27th Precinct heard about you now... ...they'd shit their
pants!

Why is あんたの今 used here instead of 今のあんた for something like “if they found out about you now…”? I think this construction is unusual because I don’t think you can say things like 私の昨日 or 彼女の3月後, at least not in this way. Is there some kind of rule or pattern here I’m missing?

Although "your now" is an uncommon expression in English, あなたの今 is a perfectly valid expression in Japanese, and it just means "your current situation". Both of 未来のあなた ("the future you") and あなたの未来 ("your future") are valid in both Japanese and English, so it shouldn't be hard to grasp the meaning itself.
To me, あなたの過去, あなたの今 and あなたの未来 sound perfectly natural, and あなたの3か月後 sounds fine when there is enough context. However, あなたの昨日 does sound uncommon and "poetic" for some reason. I think you'll just have to memorize which combinations are valid.

‘Your now’ doesn’t work in English, but the 今 equivalent of ‘your past’ and ‘your future’ works fine: it’s your present. ‘Your yesterday’ and ‘your tomorrow’ sound poetic and rather odd in English as well, though ‘all our yesterdays/tomorrows’ is fairly normal.
